# uib-datepicker-popup won't reopen

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use uib-datepicker-popup but am running into an issue that once the calendar opens and I choose a date, I cannot reopen the calendar without refreshing the screen. I step through the function call on the ng-click and it sets the is-open flag to true but the popup doesn't show after the first time.

This is the HTML:

```
<span class="input-group" >
    <input type="text" class="input-sm "  uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
           ng-model="requestDate" is-open="opened1"
           datepicker-options="dateOptions"  close-text="Close"  />
    <span class=" input-sm" >
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  ng-click="open1()">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
        </button>
    </span>
</span>
```

And the controller:

```
$scope.format = 'yyyy-MM-dd';
$scope.dateOptions = {
    'year-format': "'yy'",
    'starting-day': 1
};

$scope.open1 = function() {
    $scope.opened1 = true;
};
```

I don't understand why it won't open...any thoughts?

Comment: There's something else going on because that should work without having to refresh the page. Can you put together a snippet on your question to demonstrate the behavior you are seeing? It shouldn't matter, but you don't technically need a controller method, you could just use `ng-click="opened1 = true"` directly in the markup.

Comment: I have virtually the same html, `$scope.dateOptions`, `$scope.format`, and `ng-click` call with multiple calendars on the same page.  I have no issues like yours.  The only difference I see between our code is that I have a `popup-placement="top"` attribute

Comment: It seems to work perfectly fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/24313/

What versions of angularjs and angular-ui-bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for your help. I did a lot more searching after I posted the question and came across something that fixed the issue...not sure why it made it work but it does.

I changed the open1 function to the following...I got it to work first for one and then extended to so I can use it for all...

```
    $rootScope.openCalendar = function($event,whch) {
        $event.preventDefault();     <- I had tried this before
        $event.stopPropagation();    <- I had tried this before
        $rootScope.datepicker = {[whch]: true}; 

};
```

In my HTML I changed both lines:  (look for the <--)

```
<input type="text" class="input-sm "  uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
       ng-model="requestDate" is-open="datepicker.opened1"    <--
       datepicker-options="dateOptions"  close-text="Close"  />
<span class=" input-sm" >
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  ng-click="openCalendar($even, 'opened1')">   <--
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
    </button>
</span>
```

This works really well from what I can see so far. I guess I could shorten it a bit by using Lex's suggestion too....

Thanks again!